# HTML/CSS: Float Left

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a div,

HTML

```
<div class="preview">
       <div class="gamePreview"></div>
       <div class="gameName"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the `gameName` divs to be on top of the game Preview divs.

CSS

```
.preview {
    display: block;
}

.gamePreview, .gameName {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.gamePreview {
    width: 30%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    float: left;
}

.gameName {
    width: 29.59%;
    background-color: #494949;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 240px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This works fine when there is only one of the `preview` divs. However, if I wanted to put two divs on the same line, the `gameName` divs all float left on the same spot. Instead, I would like each `gameName` div to be on top of its own `gamePreview` div.

https://jsfiddle.net/r5t5vuqk/

[image: What I would like it to look like:]

Comment: Make a Fiddle please.

Comment: Show an image of your preferred layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/r5t5vuqk/1/). I think this is what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.preview {
    display: block;
}

.gamePreview, .gameName {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.gamePreview {
    width: 30%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    float: left;
}

.gameName {
    width: 29.59%;
    background-color: #494949;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: -10px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dpj39tk0/)

```
.preview {
   display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 30%;
}

.gamePreview, .gameName {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.gamePreview {
   background-color: lightgrey;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.gameName {
    background-color: #494949;
    clear: both;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 240px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
}
```